# Can SOL characterize its own equivalence notion, without "scaffolding," for graphs?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, higher-order-logics

Consider the following property $(*)_\mathcal{L}$ of a logic $\mathcal{L}$:

> $(*)_\mathcal{L}:\quad$ There is no $\mathcal{L}$-sentence $\varphi$ such that for all graphs $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ we have $$\mathcal{A}\equiv_{\mathcal{L}}\mathcal{B}\quad\iff\quad\mathcal{A}\oplus\mathcal{B}\models_\mathcal{L}\varphi.$$

Here a graph is just a structure in the language of a single binary relation symbol, and $\mathcal{A}\oplus\mathcal{B}$ is the structure consisting of the disjoint union of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ together with unary predicates $X,Y$ naming the "$\mathcal{A}$-part" and "$\mathcal{B}$-part" respectively.

Proving $(*)_\mathsf{FOL}$ is a fun exercise - briefly, it means that the "scaffold" built in the proof of Lindstrom's Theorem *(presented by EFT as [nose, mouth, and unibrow](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-2355-7))* is actually necessary. Unfortunately the only proof of $(*)_\mathsf{FOL}$ I know uses compactness and so is utterly unhelpful re: $(*)_{\mathsf{SOL}}$. I'll pose this question backwards since what I'm most excited about is the possibility of a different outcome:

> Is $\neg(*)_{\mathsf{SOL}}$ consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

That is, is it consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that there is a second-order sentence $\theta$ such that, for all graphs $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$, we have $$\mathcal{A}\equiv_{\mathsf{SOL}}\mathcal{B}\quad\iff\quad\mathcal{A}\oplus\mathcal{B}\models\theta?$$

I'm particularly interested in the weaker question of whether $\mathsf{ZFC+VP}\vdash(*)_{\mathsf{SOL}}$. My knee-jerk reaction is that it should, and indeed that $\mathsf{ZFC+VP}$ should prove $(*)_\mathcal{L}$ for every "reasonable" logic $\mathcal{L}$, but I don't see how to get this. On the other hand, I don't even see how to start constructing a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}+\neg(*)_\mathsf{SOL}$, under any reasonable hypotheses.